# Windows 10 on an assembled PC: how can "slmgr -dlv" show a Partial Product Key different than the one I've entered?

Tags: windows-10

long story short: I had to replace the MB of my desktop PC. I took the chance, and I ordered an used MB (same exact old model so that I kept everything else intact) and a new disk (switching to SSD). So I install the new components, I download the ISO from Microsoft's portal, I run the Windows 10 installer from USB and once I'm done I enter the Windows 10 Product Key from my COA sticker. Activation goes successfully, no prob. But if I run "slmgr -dlv" I obtain that's a Volume License and the Partial Product Key shown has nothing to do with what I entered.
As this is a generic Asus desktop motherboard, I don't expect to have any embedded OEM Product Key as you would in a classical new laptop.
Am I wrong ? Or what am I missing ?

Comment: "Am I wrong?" - Windows 10 COA stickers do not contain the license key on them.  Without knowing what the first couple characters are I can't determine if the license being displayed is the generic key for Windows 10 or not. It's not even clear what license key you actually used since, Windows 10 COA stickers on OEM devices NEVER have the license key printed on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was suggested this resource which I think clarifies the doubt: the slmgr command now works "by design" with the behaviour I observed, and the Partial Product Key it shows in recent versions of Windows 10 can not be deemed a reliable information.

> The output of the slmgr /dlv or slmgr /dli command isn't necessarily the last five (5) digits of the injected DPK. So you can no longer rely upon these commands to return the expected results.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/validate-oem-activation-key

Answer (score 0):

The used motherboard was in a different computer before and was apparently activated with a Windows license at that time. The Microsoft licensing database has that motherboard with the Windows license that was used.

You now have the motherboard and the licensing database remembers it the way it was.

If you want your own license (I am sure you do) , you will need to call Microsoft licensing support, explain, and get them to fix it.

Comment: I'd have thought, as the license belongs to the mobo & you now own the mobo, you also own the license. That would certainly apply if you bought the entire computer second hand.

Comment: What I don't understand is that once installation was complete, I went to the Control Panel, checked activation status and it correctly said "Not activated". So I did enter my Product Key, et voila: not my one. I didn't know that association between modo and Product Key was kept by Microsoft. So I should just call, explain and let them validate my own Product Key, correct ?

Comment: Yes - you should do that. See then if they will help.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft activation servers have probably identified the computer via its
hardware fingerprint, and have associated it with a previous license that was
associated with the reused parts (where the motherboard is the most important).

The simplest way to replace this key with yours is:

- Run Settings
- Click on *Update & security*
- Click on *Activation*
- Click *Change product key*
- Type your 25-digit product key
- Click *Next* to complete the process.

Comment: Unfortunately that's exactly what I did and led to the current situation.

Comment: Try [more methods](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-product-key-windows-10).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. However, if there's a MOBO-Product Key associations DB at Microsoft's, how would that change ?

Comment: Changing the key should do it on the Microsoft servers as well.

Comment: I've tried all of the above methods. Unfortunately they all led to the same result: no change.

Comment: Incredible. Try to remove the product key with the following command and reboot: `slmgr.vbs /upk`. Is Windows still activated (and with the same key)?